# How to fix error C4703 in Swig&Python?

Tags: swig

I made a c++ class following this.

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
namespace Test
{
    typedef std::pair<int, int> Values;
    class Configuration
    {
    public:
        Configuration(std::string);
        Configuration(const Configuration&);
        ~Configuration();

        void setMinVal(int);
        void setMaxVal(int);
        void setVals(Values);

        std::string getPath();
        int getMinVal();
        int getMaxVal();
        Values getVals();
    private:
        std::string path;
        int minVal;
        int maxVal;
};
```

I made swig file following this:

```
%module Test

%include <std_string.i>
%include <std_vector.i>
%include <std_pair.i>

%{
#include "Test.h"
%}

%template(Values) std::pair<int, int>;

namespace Test {

    class Configuration
    {
    public:
        Configuration(std::string);
        ~Configuration();

        void setMinVal(int);
        void setMaxVal(int);
        void setVals(std::pair<int, int>);

        std::string getPath();
        int getMinVal();
        int getMaxVal();
        std::pair<int, int> getVals();
    };
}
```

I run swig command line and compile in visual studio.
But it occurs

error C4703: potentially uninitialized local pointer variable 'p' used

In this wrapper line:

```
value_type *p;
swig_type_info *descriptor = swig::type_info<value_type>();
res = descriptor ? SWIG_ConvertPtr(obj, (void **)&p, descriptor, 0) : SWIG_ERROR;
if (SWIG_IsOK(res) && val)  *val = p;
```

In 4th line.
How can I fix it?
Thanks.

Comment: It's not uninitialised, the line above does. That really shouldn't be an error, do you have "treat warnings as errors" turned on?

Comment: Thanks. It works fine.